# Two sided bean plots with connection in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, boxplot, facet

I am trying to create two sided bean plots in R.
My data looks like:

```
> t1
   Country Women Kids
1    China     2    5
2    China     4   10
3    China     3   10
4    China     1    3
5    China     2    2
6      USA     1    1
7      USA     1    2
8      USA     2    1
9      USA     2    3
10     USA     1    0
11   Swiss     1    3
12   Swiss     2    6
13   Swiss     2    5
14   Swiss     1    2
15   Swiss     3    9
```

I tried the following using R package "beanplot":

```
> t2=melt(t1)
Using Country as id variables
> t2$C.M=paste(t2$Country,t2$variable,sep=" ")
> beanplot(value ~ C.M, data = t2, ll = 0.04,
+          main = NA, side = "both",ylab = "Count",
+          border = NA, col = list("blue", c("orange", "white")),what=c(1,1,1,1))
```

And I get the bean plots:
[Bean plots for family structure per country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBaGG.png)

However, I want a bean plot that tells the relation of pairs of points (i.e. women with kids) with connections per country. It should be something like:
[This plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vCni.jpg) but with two-sided bean plot instead of box plot for each country.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(beanplot)
library(reshape2)
library(beeswarm)

# melt
d1 <- melt(t1)
# draw the beans using the at to specify the positions, boxwex 
# to increase the size of the beans and xlim to increase the x-axis limits:

beanplot(d1$value ~ interaction(d1$variable, d1$Country), at=c(1.5,3.5,5.5), 
         side="both",col = list("blue", c("orange", "white")), what=c(1,1,1,1),
         boxwex=2, xlim=c(0,7))

# add the points
n <- beeswarm(d1$value ~ interaction(d1$variable, d1$Country), add=T, cex=2,
              pwcol =  d1$variable, pch=16)

# and finally the segments
segments(matrix(n$x,5,)[,1], d[1:5, 2], matrix(n$x,5,)[,2], d[1:5, 3], lwd= 2)
segments(matrix(n$x,5,)[,3], d[11:15, 2], matrix(n$x,5,)[,4], d[11:15, 3], lwd= 2)
segments(matrix(n$x,5,)[,5], d[6:10, 2], matrix(n$x,5,)[,6], d[6:10, 3], lwd= 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But sorry, that's not what I want. The data is for each family, say 1st family in China has 2 women and 5 kids. So, I wanted to connect these two points by, say, making some space between the two beans in China and connecting 2 in women to 5 in kids. The package "beeswarm" seems interesting. If don't find a solution maybe I'll plot the connections and overlay them manually on the beanplots.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for, but with the beans. I guess I can play with the vectors in Illustrator to get the bean on this plot. Or can we do that in R? Thank you very much.

Comment: @RimjhimRoyChoudhury Here is the solution. Please consider to accept it by clicking the button on the left side.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. This was perfect.